# Create a view of all nodes that have the same value for a specified field as the current node

Tags: nodes, views

So I have an event, which has a field called 'field_location'. I want to create a view on the event page where all other events are listed with the same location. In this case location is a node reference to a node (with content type 'location').

How can I dynamically filter all my event nodes on 'location value of the current event'?
I tried this with contextual filters but here it only checks the field you use, in this case 'field_location', with the content id of the url.

I already tried this but without success.

[image: Using PHP Code in the contextual filter]

I get zero results.

Answer (score 1):

Use Page manager and panels and add the view as a content pane. Then, pass the node's field's value as an argument to the pane(s) on the panel and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for you php code instead:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
return $node->field_location['und'][0]['target_id'];
```

Does that work?

There's a similar question with a few answers here too: [views and contextual filters with entity reference field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25148/views-and-contextual-filters-with-entity-reference-field).  There are also comments in that discussion about approaches that avoid poking around the node object and avoiding the ['und'][0] business.  Check that out too!

Comment: Alright tried that. I can't find a working solution. Is there also a way to output the value that you want to return to get an idea what's getting returned in the PHP Code?