# menu_get_object() not returning node object when view's display is Entity Reference

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities

I needed get field's value and pass it as contextual filter to "entity reference view" just described as [views and contextual filters with entity reference field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25148/views-and-contextual-filters-with-entity-reference-field/39977#39977).

But `$Node = menu_get_object()` is not retuning node object.

The scenario

**Nodes Items of custom content type**

Title : Sony LCD
Tags : electronic

Title : The godfather
Tags :Books
.
.
Items(n)

**Node of custom content type *Review.* It's node id is 10**

Title : Make a Review
Filter Tags : Taxonomy terms reference (e.x electronic, books, movies etc)

**Attach a entityform to above node using entity reference and also back referenced with enityreference_current**

My Review Item : EnityReference field - Entity reference view - Autocomplete widget
Review : text area

When node/10 is viewed, user will have to fill "my review item",but should be filter based on "Filter tags" that was already set.

Code inside VIEWS PHP under Contextual Filter

```
$node = menu_get_object ();
$ Related_ids = array ();
    $ Related = field_get_items ('node', $node, 'field_filter_tags') // Get the term reference field
    if ($related && is_array ($related) && sizeof ($related)> 0) {
      for ($i = 0; $i <count ($related); $i++) {
        $ Related_ids [] = $related [$i]['target_id'];
      }
    }
    return implode (',', $related_ids);//to perform AND
```

Update : I also tried with `$node= node_load(arg(1));` , this time $node variable set but not type of *node*. Then I `dpm(arg(1));` it shows string *autocomplete*(yes just *autocomplete* not string entered in field).

Comment: `menu_get_object` gets a loaded object from a router item. If you call it when non-node is displayed, it simply cannot return node. Where exactly do you call it? And what exactly does it return?

Comment: @Mołot entityform is attached to node like mentioned in this [thread](https://drupal.org/node/2041349#comment-7643451).Entity Form submission is done via node(in above case node/10).That means node object is displaying, am I correct?.  In php code I am checking if(isset($node)) return 1; else return 0; and it returning 0.

Comment: That *should* mean it. But if the attached part is rendered separately, that connection might be lost inside. Try to `dpr($node);` in your code and tell us what really is there, OK?

Comment: dpr($node); is not showing anything but, notice shown `Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 8 of C:\server\www\mysite.local\sites\all\modules\views\plugins\views_plugin_argument_default_php.inc(53) : eval()'d code)`.Another thing menu_get_object() is called without parameter as default is 'node'.Is it possible to use entity_metada_wrapper inside view's php code section to get node?

Comment: If `dpr(menu_get_object())` also fails, we have a problem. What you say about entity_metada_wrapper sounds reasonable, but I can't tell now, sorry.

Comment: Why not just go super-low tech and use `$node = node_load(arg(1))` if you're definitely on the node page?

Comment: @Clive I think you haven't noticed the update made to the question.I also checked that method.

Comment: @kiranking Your edit helps to make sense of it, see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

The entityreference autocomplete paths are defined in [`entityreference_menu()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entityreference!entityreference.module/function/entityreference_menu/7) as:

- entityreference/autocomplete/single/%/%/%
- entityreference/autocomplete/tags/%/%/%

The wildcard arguments are field name, entity type and bundle respectively. The [`entityreference_autocomplete_callback()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entityreference!entityreference.module/function/entityreference_autocomplete_callback/7) function also accepts an optional entity id and string parameter (the last being the search string).

So while you're expecting the path to be `node/[nid]`, it'll actually be one of the above - which explains why `arg(1)` is giving you the string `autocomplete`.

I haven't tried it but you should be able to use `arg(6)` to get the node ID in your current context.

Comment: I checked with arg(6) but failed to get node. I also checked from arg(1)_ to arg(10) and dpm that. The last entity that is fetched was "st" beyond that every args returns empty.I didn't get what exactly **st** here.`arg 1  autocomplete   | arg 2   single |  arg 3   field_select_books  |  arg 4   entityform |  arg 5   add_book  |  arg 6   NULL  | arg 7   st`

Comment: When autocomplete field is moved from entityform to its parent node then arg(6) is returning `node` as you told.  `ReviewNode title,tags,{entityform [aucomplete entity reference view]}` - **doesn't work**  `ReviewNode title,tags,[aucomplete entity reference view],{entityform}` **worked**. From this what I am getting is, it is not further backtracing beyond entityform to get its parent element :(.

Comment: I think the problem is with entityform when it is attached node.Some issues @ D.O https://drupal.org/node/2043287#comment-7750131 , https://drupal.org/node/2244987 , https://drupal.org/node/2078573